# return the Nth word from database

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get nth word from a column I'm using a code line and it works for me but there is an issue, for example:

First line is: **"the Nth word from database"**

Second line is: **"return the Nth word from database and more words"**

When I search for 6th word 'database' it returns my first line and second line but I don't want to get my first line because it has only 5 words.
thank you all

My code line:

```
SELECT *,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Text`, ' ', 6), ' ', -1) as Nth 
FROM `tbl_name`
```

Comment: I know it's because of -1 but I have no idea how to solve it :-?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having six words in you sentence means that you have to have at least five spaces, adding simlpe condition will resolve your problem:

```
select *,
       case when length(`text`) - length(replace(`text`, ' ', '')) >= 5 then
           substring_index(replace(`text`, substring_index(`text`, ' ', 5) , ''), ' ', 2)
       else null end Nth
from `tbl_name`
```

Also I changed your query, because it didn't take into account that you might not have 6th space (exactly six words).

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/efDowVH8D1cqMWQM2Z4SvK/0)

Or even more concicse:

```
select *,
       substring_index(substring_index(`text`, ' ', 5 - (length(`text`) - length(replace(sentence`text` ' ', ''))) - 1), ' ', 1)
from `tbl_name`
```

[Another demo.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/efDowVH8D1cqMWQM2Z4SvK/1)

Answer (score 0):

You should update your query with where clause, in where you can count the number of words by the following query.

```
SELECT *, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`Text`, ' ', 6), ' ', -1) as Nth 
FROM `tbl_name` 
where (COUNT(column1) - LENGTH(replace(column1, ' ', '')) > 5
```

Comment: im using mysql 4.7.9


 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

You should have to take count of spaces or whichever string which you want to take & then need to apply having-clause on that count.

```
SELECT 
    * , 
    SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(  `text` ,  ' ', 6 ) ,  ' ', -1 ) AS Nth, 
    ROUND( ( LENGTH(  `text` ) - LENGTH( REPLACE(  `text` ,  " ",  "" ) ) ) / LENGTH(  " " ) ) AS countq 
FROM  `xp_test` 
HAVING 
    countq >= 5
```

Comment: no issues but the result was as same as before
thanks for your effort  :)